# Why can I detect invalid user and password but when I use valid one I got an error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

This is my error

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `last_activity` = 1475713773, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\"' at line 1
>
> UPDATE SET `last_activity` = 1475713773, `user_data` = 'a:2:{s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";s:6:\"userID\";s:1:\"1\";}' WHERE `session_id` = '738744d19c2e9e582af4afb59826e331'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CI3/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

This is my controller:

```
function login(){
    $data['error']=0;
    if($_POST){
        $this->load->model('user');
        $username=$this->input->post('username',true);
        $password=$this->input->post('password',true);
        $user=$this->user->login($username,$password);
        if(!$user){
            $data['error']=1;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID',$user['userID']);
            //$this->session->set_userdata('user_type',$user['user_type']);
            redirect(base_url().'posts');
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer'); 
}
```

This is my model:

```
function login($username,$password){
    $where=array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password
        );
    $this->db->select()->from('users')->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array('array');
}
```

My problem is I can detect invalid username and password but if I use valid username and password i got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed several wrong in your code. Revise your model as (`select()` and `row_array()` issue)

```
function login($username,$password){
    $where = array(
        'username'=>$username,
        'password'=>$password
        );
    $this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Finally make sure your `ci_sessions' table created as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

see this is not `session_id` rather `id`

Comment: same error this is my users table

userID
email
username
password
user_type

Comment: I am saying that you have a column named `session_id` in `ci_sessions` table, this column name should be `id`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW7jPRiDs4A im following this. so i didnt know that where can i edit